# Excel: Find a value from two tables, using two inputs

Tags: excel

I am making a spreadsheet for my boss to find Freight rates. I have two tables of information:

[image: 1st Table]

[image: 2nd Table]

The idea is that we should be able to put in the first part of a postcode, and the number of pallets, and the appropriate cost will be relaid to us.

For example, if I want to send 5 pallets to BB, it should return a value of £188.06, as BB comes under Zone 2, and 5 pallets to zone 2 is £188.06.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find the appropriate function to do so.  If anyone is able to help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can the first table be re-formated to be two columns, the first with the postal code, the second with the corresponding zone?

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
[image]

I found the basic formula for searching a 2-dimensional array [here.](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array) and modified it from a `max()` value to an exact match.

`=INDEX(B15:F17,(SUMPRODUCT((B7:D9=A2)*ROW(B7:D9))-ROW(B7:D9)+1),B2)`

The sumproduct() returns the row (zone) from the first table, which is used with index() and the number of pallets returning the shipping from the second table.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in a simple way, you can use the "Zone" to have a very simple formula:

In my setup:

```
=INDEX(B11:P17,MAX((B2:R8=A21)*A2:A8),B21)
```

[image]
You need to adjust the ranges to match your data. If your "zones" are *not* exactly the way like in your example (1, 2, 3, 4...) then you need to adjust to:

```
=INDEX(B11:P17,MAX((B2:R8=A21)*ROW(A1:A7)),B21)
```

Just check that your `ROW()` has the same height as the "postcode" part and starts at the very first row.

It will always take the highest zone if a postcode is found multiple times. If a postcode isn't present at all, it will going for zone 1

> This are array-formulas and need to be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>!

Answer (score 0):

**SUGGESTION**

I'd recommend changing the layout of postcode zones to:

```
Postcode    Zone
AA          1
AB          1
AC          1
...         ...
BA          2
BB          2
BC          2
...         ...
```

That way it is much easier to look up the zone using an INDEX-MATCH.

**SOLUTION - PART 1**

However, If that isn't possible (or you just don't want to), we can split the problem down into two simpler ones.

First, we need to retrieve the zone from the postcode prefix.
To do this without an array formula, we can use SUMPRODUCT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(<Postcode Range>)-LEN(<Postcode Range>)+<Zone Range>*(<Postcode Range>=<Postcode To Search>))
```

Assuming your Zone Range is A2:A8, and your Postcode Range does not extend past column Z, and the postcode you want to search for is in C1, this would be...

=SUMPRODUCT(LEN($B$2:$Z$8)-LEN($B$2:$Z$8)+$A$2:$A$8*($B$2:$Z$8=$C$1))

**EXPLANATION OF PART 1**

What this does is creates an array filled with zeros which is the same size as your Postcode Range:

```
LEN($B$2:$Z$8)-LEN($B$2:$Z$8)
```

LEN returns an array of the number of characters in each cell. We don't care about the number of characters, so we just take it away from it's self, which leaves us with an array of the correct size filled with zeros.

To this we then add the value of the zone. So each cell in the array is filled with the corresponding Zone.

We then multiply this Zone by:

```
($B$2:$Z$8=$C$1)
```

Which will be zero, unless the postcode is the same as the one we are looking up, in which case, the zone will be multiplied by 1.

**SOLUTION - PART 2**

Now that we have found which Zone our postcode is in, it is simple to lookup the cost in Table 2 using an INDEX-MATCH-MATCH:

```
=INDEX(<Cost Range>, MATCH(<Zone To Lookup (our formula from part1)>, <Zone Range>, 0), MATCH(<Pallet Qty To Lookup>, <Pallet Qty Range>,0))
```

So, assuming Your Zone Range in Table 2 is A11:A17, and the max Pallet Qty is 15, and the Pallet Qty to find is in D1:

```
=INDEX($B$12:$P$18, MATCH(SUMPRODUCT(LEN($B$2:$Z$8)-LEN($B$2:$Z$8)+$A$2:$A$8*($B$2:$Z$8=$C$1)),$A$12:$A$18,0), MATCH($D$1,$B$11:$P$11,0))
```

**EXPLANATION OF PART 2**

The INDEX works like so:

```
=INDEX(<Range>, <Column Number>, <Row Number>)
```

We then use the MATCH functions to identify which row and column we are looking for, like this:

```
=MATCH(<Value To Match>, <Range To Search>, <Match Type>)
```

We set the Match Type to zero as we want to look for an exact match.

I hope this is clear enough to understand. If not, please let me know and I will try and expand further.

Here is a screenshot of the final solution:

[image]